# Moved Apple Google express pay option

Tags: functions

Express payment option for Google and Apple pay has moved. It use to display under 'Add Cart; button. It now appears above our options drop-down.
I have disabled and re-enabled the feature but the issue is still present.

Is there a solution or workaround?

[image]